# Is there a way to group dependencies in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.3.1",
    "@babel/register": "7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.0",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.13",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "args": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0"
  },
```

I have two build processes:

Build A -  standard app.

```
git clone <myrepo.git>
npm install
npm run build-app
deploy
```

Build B - static files

```
git clone <myrepo.git>
npm install glob args // I want to read this from package.json
npm run build-static
deploy-static
```

What I would like is to group dependencies into two groups.

The reason is installing all the dependencies takes about ~2mins. For second build task, I only need 2-3 packages which takes less than 10 seconds. Currently, I have `npm install glob args` hardcoded in my build program. I want to read it from the same package.json.

---

I cannot use dependencies vs dependencies because I have some dependencies used just for development and use the flag `npm install --production` to install only the required dependencies (without devDependencies).

Comment: Split them into dependencies and devDependencies? Then you can use `npm install --only=prod` the second time, or set `NODE_ENV=production` to do it automatically.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to control dependencies based on different build types. I cannot use environment because I need to be able to do various builds on development, qa, production.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide this context. Your dependency list doesn't show any `devDependencies`, for example. How many environments? Why do they have different dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install subset of dependencies with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886871/install-subset-of-dependencies-with-npm)

Answer (score -1):

You can surely group them; there are two types of dependencies, one's dev and the other one is production.  Here's a reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

If you want to create more than two, check this package out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-dependencies

Comment: That package didn't work for me. https://github.com/itsthatguy/group-dependencies/issues/13