# npm install subset of dependencies in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm using npm to handle my dependencies for a typescript project.

In one step of my CI process, I'm performing integration tests. The only dependencies I need for that are Jest and  Pactum. Currently I'm running `npm install` to get the correct versions of those dependencies, but it feels like overkill when I only need two of them. It costs pipeline minutes, and just takes time.

Is there any way to specify install of a dependency and use the version that is defined in the package file?

So like `npm install package@version`, but I don't want to repeat the version because it is already defined in package.json and will surely break sooner or later. So basically, I'd want to specify another section alongside `devDependencies` called `integrationTestDependencies`.

Comment: Have you considered using npx commands for this?

Comment: I've tried using npx and it suffers from the same issue, it forces me to specify the version again and does not use the semver version from package.json

Comment: Have you tried removing the tilde/caret in package.json before npm install? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41003470/4722345

Comment: Related suggests third party packages for subsets of deps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40886871/4722345

Comment: i'm using caret for parcel for instance, in my package.json that is `^1.12.4`. If I run `npm install` and then `npx parcel --version` I get `1.12.4`. If I remove `node_modules` and run `npx parcel --version`  I get `2.0.0-beta.2`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I clicked the first few links that were suggested but I missed that. Both of the suggested dependencies solve my issue,  so this is a duplicate. I'll give those a try. Thank you

Comment: Yes thank you, I've flagged this as a duplicate