# How to "npm install" only specific dependencies automatically from package.json. (Ex. based on CLI command you only install server side dependencies)

Tags: json, npm, package, dependencies, package.json

Trying to find a way to split the dependencies installation into groups in your root's package.json file.

So, instead of just running "npm install" when cloning code and installing all dependencies. Say instead you ONLY want to install specific/designated dependencies in your package.json so you have the option of only installing a piece/group of the entire dependencies list. Something similar to running a script, but just for specifying what dependencies you want npm to install. So, could you make a script similar to "npm run start" or "npm run dev" but each script only installs specific dependencies from the package.json file.

This way you have the option of having all of your dependencies in one file location, but you also have the option of installing all of them, or only installing some of them without having to type out each dependencies name in the CLI that is in the package.json list that you want to specifically install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install subset of dependencies with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886871/install-subset-of-dependencies-with-npm)